# Has any (nominally) democratic government ever been domestically overthrown without military assistance?

Tags: revolution

When looking at historically overthrown governments, all of those that I can recall have fallen in one or more of these buckets:

- They were of monarchies, or
- They received domestic assistance from the military, or
- They received assistance from a foreign power

So this has made me wonder: what examples, if any, are there of successful revolutions that:

- Overthrew democracies/republics (at least in name, even if not in practice), and
- Did not receive cooperation from the country's military forces, and
- Did not receive assistance from a foreign power?

By "overthrow", I mean something illegal -- I'm referring to scenarios where some portion of the general population revolts and illegally overthrows the government, not merely situations where the power is exercised or shifted through legal maneuvers (however shocking they might be). So for example, if the US Congress amended the constitution tomorrow to dissolve the entire government and personally make me dictator, that wouldn't count, because it would be perfectly legal. OTOH, if Jan 6 replaced the president with some king, then that would count.

I'm trying to see if there's any historical precedent whatsoever suggesting that the general populace of a democracy(-in-name) actually have any chance of overthrowing a regime that still has military support, without external interference

Comment: You mean like the [Weimar Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weimar_Republic#End_of_the_Weimar_Republic)? Or the switch from a Parliament to [The Protectorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Protectorate) in the UK?

Comment: @T.E.D.: I'm not sure those quite fit. By "overthrow", I mean something illegal -- I'm referring to scenarios where some portion of the general population revolts and illegally overthrows the government, not merely situations where the power is exercised or shifted through legal maneuvers (however shocking they might be). So for example, if the US Congress amended the constitution tomorrow to dissolve the entire government and personally make me dictator, that wouldn't count, because it would be perfectly legal. OTOH, if Jan 6 replaced the president with some king, then that would count.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Basically, I'm trying to see if there's any historical precedent whatsoever suggesting that the general populace of a democracy(-in-name) actually have any chance of overthrowing a regime that still has military support, without external interference.

Comment: What is your definition of "foreign assistance"? E.g. that the main character of the October Revolution in Russia received "logistical" and financial support from Germany is well documented. Does that count already? Or only armed intervention?

Comment: Also what is your definition of "military"? Would Sudan's RSF count as military? Or Wagner in Russia?

Comment: @T.E.D. It certainly wasn't called "the UK" in Cromwell's day. Indeed the difficulty of governing multiple kingdoms is what many historians point to as the cause of the English Civil War.

Comment: @Jan: I think it wouldn't count, though that's a good question. If it could be plausibly seen as a coup d'état, it wouldn't count.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)  I suspect that any adequate definition of terms  will answer the question.

Comment: @T.E.D.  The Weimar Republic's military were involved in the Nazi's coming to power.  Weimar Military Officers were involved in the Beer Hall Putsch,  and they stood down in exchange for the elimination of the Brown Shirts in the Night of the Long Knives.  They made a deal with Hitler in order for Hitler to escape the box the Weimar politicians like Papen had entrapped him in.   Chancellor with only 3 of 11  Cabinet seats,  and one of those without portfolio.

Comment: *Cooperation of military forces* can be as little as refusing to shoot or staying in their headquarters or simply being deliberately too slow to stop the revolution - e.g., as happened in Russia in 1991. Yet, this neutrality may have profound effect.

Answer (score 10):

The [end of the GDR](https://www.britannica.com/place/Germany/The-reunification-of-Germany) mastches all of your points:

Although a firm communist part of the Warsaw pact, it called itself "German *Democratic* Republic" and held elections regularly. They obviously did not amnount to the "fair and free" standards of actual democracies, but in name and by fake ceremonies, they were "democratic" and a "republic".

The military was considered to be on the side of the government. While their *inaction* and hesitation to shed their own citizen's blood en masse had some serious influence, there was no action in favor of the "revolutionaries".

While the protestors certainly had moral support (and probably some minor logistical though any intelligence service active in East Berlin) it wasn't a planned coup by a foreign power. Or a foreign powers military supporting.

Comment: +1, though I guess I wasn't really considering the scenario where the military would just stand by and spectate. For the sake of completeness, and in the interest of avoiding me asking a second question that is ever-so-slightly different from this one: do you happen to know of any examples where the military actually supported the government? (Or should I just modify the question to say this?)

Comment: Like in 1953? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_German_uprising_of_1953. None that were successful. I mean the military is the military. They can eradicate the whole country if they wanted. The military needs at least be sympathetic enough to not go on a genocidal killing spree. Show at least *some* inaction.

Comment: There is at least one country (Iceland) where the military lacks the power to prevent an uprising by the population. However, an uprising there seems very unlikely.

Comment: @nvoigt: Got it, thanks! And it sounds like you see that as being universally true regardless of whether the current government is a democracy, monarchy, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The [Articles of Confederation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Articles_of_Confederation) are probably the best example of a (set of) democratic governments overthrown by an extra-legal non military force.  The Articles had (effectively) no military, so they weren't a factor.

OP adds,

> When you refer to the articles of confederation, are you referring to the existing state governments being overthrown? Because "overthrow" isn't quite the impression I had there - the governments deliberately sent representatives with the intention of forming the union, so it happened with their consent. Whether or not there were specific laws on the books allowing for this procedure (I have no idea honestly) I guess seems like a mere technicality than anything else. –

I can't cite anything terse, but it is the consensus of most historians that I've read (I believe that [P. Maier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauline_Maier) might have been the first to articulate it) that the Constitution was  not an evolution of the articles. It is very clear that the intent of the convention was to amend the Articles, but that a small cabal (Washington, Hamilton, Jay, Madison, et. al.) usurped the Convention to advocate for a completely different government. Probably the most convincing point is that the Articles were a pact among the States, while the Constitution was very explicitly submitted to the **people** not the **states**.  The signatories of the Articles were not permitted to participate in the process of selecting the new government, and directly to OP's point, while there was a procedure for amending the Articles, it was not followed. The Constitution was neither an amendment to, nor an evolution of the Articles, but a completely novel arrangement.

[West Virginia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_West_Virginia#:%7E:text=In%20a%20referendum%20on%20May,of%20the%20Ordinance%20of%20Secession.) probably also qualifies, as might the many governments of pre-federal Pennsylvania.

@T.E.D's example of the [Protectorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Protectorate) seems to fit.  As does the [Glorious Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glorious_Revolution) (unless you're going to exclude constitutional monarchies from democracies, which I think is ... ..I'm groping for a term, but I think that makes the definition so fuzzy and subjective as to no longer be in scope.   At that point you're looking for a left handed red headed non-binary Eskimo with a nice personality and 32 cents in their left rear pocket, and if we find one, you'll argue about the coins in the 32 cents )

The first French Republic is arguable. One could argue that elements of the military contributed to the evolution from Republic to consulate, but if "elements of the military" is the condition then the question becomes nigh on impossible, since it would require either the total absence of a military or some external cause which prevented a single military person from participating.

The [Russian Provisional Government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Provisional_Government) probably demonstrates another edge condition. My sense is that you're looking for established democratic governments with a record of effective governance that last for at least a generation.  [Aside: I get nervous when we start hedging a fuzzy definition with a set of even more fuzzy constraints].  When Karensky decided to flee the possibility of German invasion, the government was essential done.  (I don't consider the German advance to be the "assistance of a foreign power", since this wasn't part of the German strategic aims)

I'd argue that any republican government ought to fit your definition - "democracy" used to be a negative term referring to mob rule, while republics had actual governance.

In Republican Rome important decisions were voted on by various assemblies.  We'd argue with their franchise and their conduct of elections, but I don't see either of those constraints in the question.  Rome fell to an autocracy with no external influence.  Republican Rome fell several times before they gave up the ghost and the Senate.

Athens was democratic, but lost control to a tyrant. It has been too long since I read enough Athenian history to comment intelligently.

At the risk of further fuzzing a currently subjective example, I'd suggest that you restrict this to  constitutional democratic or republican nation-states, which would toss out Greece & Rome, and then again find some time frame which would block the other examples.  (some historians consider the American revolution to not end until the Constitution was passed). I suspect that *many* revolutionary governments undergo revolutions that fit your stated criteria but not your intent.

Comment: When you refer to the articles of confederation, are you referring to the existing state governments being overthrown? Because "overthrow" isn't quite the impression I had there - the governments deliberately sent representatives with the intention of forming the union, so it happened with their consent. Whether or not there were specific laws on the books allowing for this procedure (I have no idea honestly) I guess seems like a mere technicality than anything else.

Comment: "*The signatories of the Articles were not permitted to participate in the process of selecting the new government*" Who supposedly decided that? John Dickinson, Daniel Carroll, Gouverneur Morris, Roger Sherman, and Robert Morris signed both documents. Every state sent delegates. Every state signed. Congress of the Confederation unanimously sent the Constitution to the states who unanimously ratified it. That's not an overthrow, that's unanimous consent. The rest is legal minutia.

Comment: West Virginia, I would argue, had the backing of the US military. Without it, it would not have remained in existence for long.

Comment: the _states_ were the signatories of the Articles. The individuals you name were acting on behalf of their states. The Constitution was submitted to the _people_, not to the state governments.

Comment: @MCW Huh? Each state legislature had to ratify the Constitution.

Comment: @Spencer, do you have a citation for that? Every source I've read said that the Constitution was submitted to the population, specifically not to the state legislature. I'll see if I can find a quote in Eliis' _The Quartet_ later today. Not sure if I've got Maier around the house to quote.

Comment: @MCW [Here](https://csac.history.wisc.edu/2021/03/31/ratification-of-the-u-s-constitution-an-overview-of-the-process/).  No state had an extra-legal "popular uprising", unauthorized by the legislature, that told the state government "This state is adopting the Constitution whether you like it or not".  It was the state legislatures that called the ratifying conventions, or (in the case of Rhode Island) called for a state-wide referendum to adopt the Constitution.

Comment: I never said "popular uprising".

Comment: +1 I think in Kerensky example one could probably count the passage given to Lenin and others via the German territory as an *assistance of a foreign power*. Although the Bolsheviks were not assisted by military, they were assisted by numerous military troops acting without their officers. However, as you correctly pointed out, this is a very fuzzy example.